# Custom .css not loading into Flask HTML template

Tags: html, css, flask

I am having a nightmare getting custom css to load into a Flask HTML template. I have tried everything I can think of, and haven't really had this issue before but am stumped now. File tree as follows:

```
/static
   /css
       styles.css
/templates
    index.html
main.py
```

Index.html is rendering correctly, but css is not applied or loaded. index css link as follows:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='css/styles.css') }}">
</head>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: in your main.py have you set the static folder, i.e app.static_folder = 'static'

Comment: 'static' is the default folder name though right? I've never previously declared the static folder unless I've used something other than 'static'

Comment: yes, but since you have not posted what is in your main.py I can only take a guess as to where the problem may be

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [css externally](https://www.javatpoint.com/external-css) without using 'url_for'.
In your case try the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./static/css/styles.css">
```

Comment: Had tried this, still no joy, just renders index with no styling applied

Comment: Okay. Make sure that you have added 'dot' before '/static/css/styles.css'.